# Getting "java.sql.SQLException: Line contains wrong number of columns" using CsvJDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using CsvJdbc (it is a JDBC-driver for csv-files) to access a csv-file. But while reading the csv it is throwing the below Exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Line contains wrong number of columns: 5 13
    at org.relique.jdbc.csv.CsvReader.getEnvironment(Unknown Source)
    at org.relique.jdbc.csv.CsvResultSet.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.quicklyjava.MLUData.mlu(MLUData.java:66)
    at com.quicklyjava.MLUData.main(MLUData.java:118)
```

It is printing the output, but after that it is throwing the above mentioned Exception. It shows that it is reading the csv.
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7aDLPFJOqw7T0k2YUNLckVsUjQ/edit?usp=sharing) is the link to csv file. Could someone help me on this? Thanks in advance !

Here is the code:

```
      Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
Class.forName("org.relique.jdbc.csv.CsvDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:relique:csv:D:\\CSVs");
props.put("separator", ",");
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String query = "SELECT * FROM "
                        + locale.getCsvFileName()
                        + " WHERE ID =".concat("'").concat(adpItemId)
                                .concat("'");
                ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                System.out.println("Locale is: " + locale.getCsvFileName());

                while (results.next()) {System.out.println(results
                            .getString("Object_Type_Name"));

                }
                listMLU.add(mlu);
                // System.out.println("Done for "+locale.getCsvFileName());

                // clean up
                results.close();
                stmt.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? It reads a line that has more (or less) columns than previous lines it read. Either the line is really wrong, or the CSV file is escaped incorrectly (or different than expected by this driver). Without more information (eg a sample of the file contents that triggers the error), there is not a lot we can do.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have shared the link to the CSV file. Can You please have a look again?

Comment: I took a quick glance, but I don't see anything obvious wrong with the file

Comment: Open the CSV file in Excel, put a filter on column M, set the filter to show only blanks and you will quite quickly see that row 232 has fewer entries than the rows above it.

Answer (score 0):

There are way too many records here for one to manually look for the error.  My suggestion would be to implement an algorithm to verify you have 12 commas for each line and figure out where the problem or problems lie.